# OpenShift Origin clone from own git repo error

Tags: git, ssh, ssl-certificate, openshift-origin

In our company, we're using own Git repository with self-signed certificate.

If I try to build a new App in OpenShift from out git repository it doesn't accept our certificate (look at log below). Just using *git clone* results in no error, so the cause is probably in OpenShift's own git client.

Here are the details from *oc build-logs*:

If it tries to clone repo via ssh:

```
I1005 09:26:33.661857       1 docker.go:203] Cloning source from ssh://username@git-repo-url:port/blablabla/xyz.git
E1005 09:26:33.718445       1 git.go:102] Clone failed: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Via https:

```
I1005 11:49:52.134760       1 docker.go:203] Cloning source from https://username@git-repo-url:port/blablabla/xyz.git
E1005 11:49:52.392426       1 git.go:102] Clone failed: fatal: unable to access 'https://username@git-repo-url:port/blablabla/xyz.git': Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
F1005 11:49:52.392460       1 builder.go:54] Build error: exit status 128
```

*sslVerify* in .gitconfig is set to false.

Any ideas how to make OpenShift accept the certificate or just ignore it?
Many thanks!

P.S. OpenShift Origin was installed this way:
https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/master/README_origin.md

Upd: Tried following solution with no effect:
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds.html#using-private-repositories-for-builds

Versions:

```
oc v1.0.6-2-ge2a02a8 
kubernetes v1.1.0-alpha.0-1605-g44c91b1
```

Comment: How was OpenShift Origin setup? I'm assuming if you used the `docker` tag that you used these instructions? https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#running-in-a-docker-container

Comment: I put this information in the main question now

Comment: are you including the .gitconfig containing the sslVerify setting in your build?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to provide a .gitconfig via a Secret was only recently added to OpenShift, how current is your deployment?

The instructions for how to supply a .gitconfig (including setting sslVerify) are here: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/builds.html#other-authentication

Comment: That's exactly what I tried with no success. The deployment is ca. 2 weeks old..

`oc v1.0.6-2-ge2a02a8
kubernetes v1.1.0-alpha.0-1605-g44c91b1`